# How can I load a class file when needed in java

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have two different projects and two projects use same core jar file. First project gets data from Web Service and another project does not need web service. In core jar file, I load some classes from web serivce jar file, but another project does not use this web serivce jar file. So when I deploy second project to Jboss server or build on Maven, it reported that there are some missing classes in core jar file for second project which does not need web service.

SO I wan to ask How can I load java class file dynamically when deploy to Jboss or build on Maven? Class only loaded when it exist, Is Java Reflection an option?

Comment: Split your project in dependent modules. Use maven to set dependencies.

Comment: I agree with @BoristheSpider, but I'd like to add that it's a common pattern where a utility project contains implementations that not every dependent project needs. As long as they're not instantiated that is not necessarily a problem. I've seen projects where application context files (Spring beans files) followed a convention such that the dependent project knew what files to expect on the class path, giving them the choice to instantiate those or not.

Comment: Also, let me predict your future: some day you're gonna hate yourself for calling this project "core". That means nothing, it will be an open door to add all sorts of stuff that have nothing to do with each other, it will grow like weeds. Give it a clear, descriptive name of the domain or function that is its responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Boris and Sander,

I have two different workspaces : NextiraOne built with persistance project, core project and Shop project. Franke workspace built with persistance project, core, shop project and additional ws-client-franke project.

I already defined in pom.xml of core project like this:

```
<profile>
        <id>default-mandant</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <!-- If no mandant was specified then activate this profile -->
                <name>!bl.config.mandant</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <!-- Choose your default mandant (nextiraone/franke) -->
            <bl.config.mandant>nextiraone</bl.config.mandant>
        </properties>
    </profile>


<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sharis.p7.customizer</groupId>
        <artifactId>ws-client-${bl.config.mandant}</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

ws-client-franke is already there for Franke workspace but I don't want to define another project ws-client-nextiraone because nextiraone workspace does not need web service.

Because two workspaces use same core project so when I import like this in core

```
import com.sharis.p7.webservice.client.franke.order.delivery.DeliveryData;
```

and with deploy to Jboss server or build on Maven, into NextiraOne workspace reported that DeliveryData class cannot be found.